# Amcharts V4 mark values on series with known value

Tags: amcharts

I have a amChart4 XYChart loaded from a CSV external file.

How to mark the max values on a serie, max values are known when writing the file. So just need to mark the data points with a bullet.

**var maxNm = 404.24;**

**var maxHP = 327.7;**

Se code with working chart loaded from CSV.

https://codepen.io/lasse-kofoed/pen/WNbNXxe

```
// Themes begin
    am4core.useTheme(am4themes_material);
    am4core.useTheme(am4themes_animated);
// Themes end

// Create chart instance
    var chart = am4core.create("chartdiv", am4charts.XYChart);

    chart.responsive.enabled = true;        

// Set up data source
    chart.dataSource.url = "https://master.tus.io/files/a6bfda6a8051313c0c0b1d7129a75786+DB7aQwWVBca.GAK4H6FLamUT58549Asv6vLoR9kEJySMEVOsFlCSi9eqzgMYLhqXdMJDZoTE0C90HuVUUKD7KoKdFjlM0f1IRkkQ0L5X6iykr8kSsyNWTtPkcmzIFwDp";

    chart.dataSource.parser = new am4core.CSVParser();
    chart.dataSource.parser.options.useColumnNames = true;

// Increase contrast by taking evey second color
    chart.colors.step = 2;

    chart.dataSource.events.on("error", function (ev) {
      console.log("Oopsy! Something went wrong");        
    });


// Create value axis
    var valueAxis = chart.yAxes.push(new am4charts.ValueAxis());
    valueAxis.tooltip.disabled = true;
    valueAxis.title.text = "Power & Torque";

    var categoryAxis = chart.xAxes.push(new am4charts.CategoryAxis());
    categoryAxis.dataFields.category = "Rpm";

// Create serie Nm
    var nm = chart.series.push(new am4charts.LineSeries());
    var maxNm = 404.24;
    nm.dataFields.valueY = "Nm";
    nm.dataFields.categoryX = "Rpm";
    nm.yAxis = valueAxis;
    nm.name = "Nm";
    nm.strokeWidth = 1;
    //nm.tensionX = 0.7;
    nm.tooltipText = "{valueY.value} Nm";

    var hp = chart.series.push(new am4charts.LineSeries());
    var maxHP = 327.7;
    hp.dataFields.valueY = "Hp";
    hp.dataFields.categoryX = "Rpm";
    hp.yAxis = valueAxis;
    hp.name = "Hp";
    hp.strokeWidth = 1;
    //hp.tensionX = 0.7;
    hp.tooltipText = "{valueY.value} Hp";

// Add legend
    chart.legend = new am4charts.Legend();

// Add cursor
    chart.cursor = new am4charts.XYCursor();
```

Answer (score 0):

**Updated a CodePen with the result.** 
https://codepen.io/lasse-kofoed/pen/eYmprPR

Found that using the event beforedatavalidated you can alter the data and set a field to false.

And then set propertyFields.disabled = true on a bullet object ( hides all bullets )
and .propertyFields.disabled to the field name that was added to the data list item ( show on bullets on values that have the field set to false )

```
chart.series.values[0].dataItem.values.valueY
```

Also found that the max and min values can be found here, but is not using that information in the example

```
// Add max Torque bullet
var maxTorque = nm.bullets.push(new am4charts.CircleBullet());
maxTorque.disabled = true;
maxTorque.propertyFields.disabled = "maxTorque";
maxTorque.radius = 8;
maxTorque.strokeWidth = 2;
maxTorque.stroke = am4core.color("#fff");
var maxTorqueLabel = nm.bullets.push(new am4charts.LabelBullet());
maxTorqueLabel.label.text = "Max torque\n[bold]{valueY} {name}@{categoryX}[/]";
maxTorqueLabel.disabled = true;
maxTorqueLabel.propertyFields.disabled = "maxTorque";
maxTorqueLabel.label.dy = -30;

// Add max Power bullet
var maxPower = hp.bullets.push(new am4charts.CircleBullet());
maxPower.disabled = true;
maxPower.propertyFields.disabled = "maxPower";
var maxPowerLabel = hp.bullets.push(new am4charts.LabelBullet());
maxPowerLabel.label.text = "Max power\n[bold]{valueY} {name}@{categoryX}[/]";
maxPowerLabel.disabled = true;
maxPowerLabel.propertyFields.disabled = "maxPower";
maxPowerLabel.label.dy = -30;

chart.events.on("beforedatavalidated", function(ev) { 

  var maxT = chart.data.find(x => x.Rpm === "5221");
  var maxP = chart.data.find(x=> x.Rpm === "5888");
  if(typeof maxT !== "undefined")
  {  
    maxT.maxTorque = false; 
  }
  if(typeof maxP !== "undefined")
  {  
    maxP.maxPower = false;  
  }  
});
```